# How can I call a rust function from R that returns Vec<Vec<f64>>?

Tags: r, rust, ffi, extendr, rextendr

I have implemented a function for sampling from M different normal distributions N times in Rust because my R code was too slow. It is also parallelized. Here is the pure Rust code:

```
    use rand_distr::{Normal, Distribution};
    use rayon::prelude::*;

    fn rust_rprednorm(n: i32, means: Vec<f64>, sds: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<Vec<f64>> {

        let mut preds = vec![vec![0.0; n as usize]; means.len()];

        preds.par_iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(i, e)| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            (0..n).into_iter().for_each(|j| {
                let normal = Normal::new(means[i], sds[i]).unwrap();
                e[j as usize] = normal.sample(&mut rng);
            })
        });

        preds
    }
```

Which I am trying to call from R using the rextendr library. The code is inside a utils.R file I import using source():

```
code <- r"(
    use rand_distr::{Normal, Distribution};
    use rayon::prelude::*;

    #[extendr]
    fn rust_rprednorm(n: i32, means: Vec<f64>, sds: Vec<f64>) -> Vec<Vec<f64>> {

        let mut preds = vec![vec![0.0; n as usize]; means.len()];

        preds.par_iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(i, e)| {
            let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
            (0..n).into_iter().for_each(|j| {
                let normal = Normal::new(means[i], sds[i]).unwrap();
                e[j as usize] = normal.sample(&mut rng);
            })
        });

        preds
    }
)"

rust_source(code = code, dependencies = list(`rand` = "0.8.5", `rand_distr` ="0.4.3", `rayon` = "1.6.1"))
```

The error is:

```
Error in `invoke_cargo()`:
! Rust code could not be compiled successfully. Aborting.
✖ error[E0277]: the trait bound `Robj: From<Vec<Vec<f64>>>` is not satisfied
 --> src\lib.rs:6:5
  |
6 |     #[extendr]
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `From<Vec<Vec<f64>>>` is not implemented for `Robj`
  |
  = help: the following other types implement trait `From<T>`:
            <Robj as From<&'a [T]>>
            <Robj as From<&Altrep>>
            <Robj as From<&Primitive>>
            <Robj as From<&Robj>>
            <Robj as From<&Vec<T>>>
            <Robj as From<&extendr_api::Complexes>>
            <Robj as From<&extendr_api::Doubles>>
            <Robj as From<&extendr_api::Environment>>
          and 71 others
  = note: this error originates in the attribute macro `extendr` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
✖ error: aborting due to previous error
Traceback:

1. source("inla_predictive_distribution_utils.R")
2. withVisible(eval(ei, envir))
3. eval(ei, envir)
4. eval(ei, envir)
5. rust_source(code = code, dependencies = list(rand = "0.8.5", 
 .     rand_distr = "0.4.3", rayon = "1.6.1"))
6. invoke_cargo(toolchain = toolchain, specific_target = specific_target, 
 .     dir = dir, profile = profile, quiet = quiet, use_rtools = use_rtools)
7. check_cargo_output(compilation_result, message_buffer, tty_has_colors(), 
 .     quiet)
8. ui_throw("Rust code could not be compiled successfully. Aborting.", 
 .     error_messages, call = call, glue_open = "{<{", glue_close = "}>}")
9. withr::with_options(list(warning.length = message_limit_bytes), 
 .     rlang::abort(message, class = "rextendr_error", call = call))
10. force(code)
11. rlang::abort(message, class = "rextendr_error", call = call)
12. signal_abort(cnd, .file)
```

I figured a nested vector would be supported since a regular vector is, but it appears not, do I need to implement this trait for Robj, or is there another way to go about it? I am also not sure if this is the recommended way to call Rust code from R.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to implement Robj for Vec anyway.

Comment: The error lists some impls, just take a `& mut [f64]` for means and sds, as you don't seem to ever add or remove elements from them.

Comment: @IvanC Thanks for your help. I tried changing the parameter types to &mut [f64], but to no avail. I think the issue is the return type needs to be something that Robj has a From trait for. My end goal is to have a dataframe/matrix where a row represents a distribution and columns are the n sample from it, but I figured there may not beconversions from polars/ndarray or some similar library to R's matrix/data.frame/data.table. Hence why I went with nested vectors as I figured they would be implemented

Answer (score 1):

You cannot return something like `Vec<Vec<T>>` because `R` does not really understand such things. I suspect that your best options are

- Some sort of a 2d matrix if the output is rectangular

  - There is an `Rmatrix` type just for that
  - There is limited support for `ndarray`, which is also translated into R matrix
- A `List` containing `Vec<T>` elements if the output is a jagged array

Answer (score 1):

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75678447/12545041) by Ilia, you cannot return a `Vec<Vec<f64>>` to R. As your code creates a matrix, you can use [`extendr_api::wrapper::matrix::RMatrix`](https://extendr.github.io/extendr/extendr_api/wrapper/matrix/type.RMatrix.html):

```r
code <- r"(
    use rand_distr::{Normal, Distribution};
    use rayon::prelude::*;

    #[extendr]
    fn rust_rprednorm(n: i32, means: Vec<f64>, sds: Vec<f64>) -> RArray<f64, [usize; 2]> {
        let mut preds = vec![vec![0.0; n as usize]; means.len()];

        preds.par_iter_mut().enumerate().for_each(|(i, e)| {
            let mut rng: rand::prelude::ThreadRng = rand::thread_rng();
            (0..n).into_iter().for_each(|j| {
                let normal: Normal<f64> = Normal::new(means[i], sds[i]).unwrap();
                e[j as usize] = normal.sample(&mut rng);
            })
        });
        let matrix = RArray::new_matrix(means.len() as usize, n as usize, |r, c| preds[r][c]);
        matrix
    }
)"
rextendr::rust_source(code = code, dependencies = list(`rand` = "0.8.5", `rand_distr` ="0.4.3", `rayon` = "1.6.1"))
```

This can be then called as follows:

```r
rust_rprednorm(n = 6, means = c(1,2,3), sds = c(4,5,6))
#           [,1]       [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]        [,6]
# [1,]  5.068423  3.2048321 -2.669690  0.191781 -2.666059 -11.9706997
# [2,] -1.470927  0.4335488  3.394352  0.242292 -2.040637   3.1623452
# [3,]  6.802815 -3.2444519  7.862181 10.063047  9.297888   0.7607057
```